# Limit of a function whose factors' limits are 0 and $\infty$

Tags: limits

If $\lim_{x\to 0+}f=0^+$ and $\lim_{x\to 0+}g=-\infty$, then what is $\lim_{x\to 0+}fg$ ? Could it only be 0 or $\infty$? Why?

I've tried $\arctan(x)\ln(x)$ which converges to 0... I don't the l'Hopital Rule can be used for this since $\frac{f'}{g'}$ DNE right?

Comment: There is something called [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hopital%27s_rule)

Comment: By $\ast$ do you mean the product or the convolution? If the product, there is no way to know prior to the calculation. $x \cot(x)$ goes to $1$ as $x \to 0$ for instance, so you're not even stuck between your two proposed choices.

Comment: It would be a mistake to think that knowing the limits of f and of g that this question assumes is enough information to determine the limit of fg.  It is not. Consider f(x) = x^p and g(x) = -c/x^q for some positive constants c, p, q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions state that one function is getting small, and one is getting large (in absolute value) as $x \to 0^+$. This doesn't mean that their product has to be $0$ or $\infty$ - their product can balance out, and converge to any non positive real number or $-\infty$.

Take any $c \in (-\infty, 0]$. Then, let $f(x) = cx$, and let $g(x) = -1/x$. Notice that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x) = -\infty$, so they satisfy the conditions of the problem. Then, $f *g$ is the constant function $c$, so we have $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)g(x) = c$. Therefore, the limit $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)g(x)$ can be any non-positive real number.

You already have an example where their limit is negative infinity, so the limit can also be $-\infty$. Furthermore, the limit cannot be positive or $\infty$, since $f$ approaches $0$ from the positive side and $g$ approaches  *negative* infinity, so the product $fg$ is negative as $x \to 0^+$.